# I want to raise an error if the entered month is grater than current month

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def generate_leave(self, cr, uid,ids, fields, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        month_split = self.browse( cr, uid,ids)
        print "\n\n\n\n\n\n DATEE",month_split.name 
        dt =  datetime.strptime(month_split.name, "%Y-%m-%d")
        year = dt.year
        print "\n\n\n\n YER",year
        month = dt.month
        print "\n\n\n MNTH",month
        hrme=self.pool.get('acm.lev')
        fds = hrme.search(cr,uid,[('no_of_months' ,'=', dt.month),('no_of_year' ,'=', dt.year)])
        print "\n\n\n\n\n TEST FDS",fds
        if month == (dt.month + 1) % 12 or 12 :
            raise osv.except_osv(_("Warning!"),_("Please choose months properly."))
```

It is working properly.
 
But it is showing same raise error if I choose the month Feb also in my case I want a raised error only if entered month is greater than the current month.
 If it is lesser than the current month the raise error should not throw.

Comment: `12` is always true, so `... or 12` is always true.

Comment: So what should i want to do. If am selecting a month which is lesser than current month it should not throw warning.

Comment: Any answer for my question?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. 
First we want to fetch "CURRENT MONTH" and then we want to give that "CURRENT MONTH" like :

```
if month > datetime.now().month : 
 raise osv.except_osv(_("Warning!"),_("Please choose months properly."))
```

–